# Does any theory explain the tendency for toddlers to desire objects held by other toddlers?

Tags: developmental-psychology

Very often, I observe that a toddler `A` who currently focuses their attention on a specific toy or activity becomes distracted if another toddler `B` begins playing with an object `O` that `A` played with previously.

Subsequently, `A` shifts their attention to `B` and `O` and aborts their current activity, even though it often appears that `A` was fully engaged in the previous activity and no resources for attention shift were free. Most times, `A` approaches `B` and a dispute about `O` arises.

For me, it seems to be a basic need of a toddler, although I can't find a specific theory that provides a coherent description of my observation.

**Does any cognitive science theory explain the tendency for toddlers to desire objects held by other toddlers?**

Comment: I'm on the same. No theory found.
Although, I recommend You see this page: http://www.earlyinterventionsupport.com/qa-3-year-old-child-will-share/ - The overview of behavior it's a bit similar with your research.